# commands no longer working

Tags: tables, math-mode

Two commands I've been using for years no longer work:

1. the apostrophe (') in math mode no longer produces a prime sign, it crashes the typesetting procedure and I get the error message:

```
    ->\futurelet 
                 \next \h@ngrqtest 
    l.48    k(v^\prime) = k^0(v'\mbox
                                   {'})\exp(-\lambda_v f_v)
     ./TestFile.tex:48:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have to use `^\prime` to create a prime sign.

2. `\multicolumn{1}{c}{text…}` no longer centers the text in a left- or right-aligned column, nor does any `\multicolumn{1}` command work to change the alignment of one cell entry.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide not just some more or less unintelligible error messages but a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), i.e., a sample LaTeX document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. Please also state which TeX distribution (MikTeX?, TeXLive?, something else?) you employ and when it was last updated.

Comment: obviously `'` and `\mulicolumn` work by default so you have some non standard definitions, we could debug if you showed an example

Comment: `hanging.sty` is presumably involved

Comment: This? `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{hanging}\begin{document}\[K' x\]\end{document}`

Comment: As far as I can see `hanging` package has always made `'` unusable in math mode.

Answer (score 6):

The `hanging` package is incompatible with using `'` in math.

https://github.com/wspr/herries-press/issues/47

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\begin{document}
\[K' x\]
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
'->\futurelet 
              \next \h@ngrqtest 
l.4 \[K' 
         x\]
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

As the non-active `'` is re-inserted, but as this is math-active, it loops.

Note that this has always been the case, presumably your older documents were not using this package.

Answer (score 3):

This has never worked, because `hanging` overrides the meaning of the active `'` needed in math.

It can be fixed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}

\makeatletter
\catcode`'=\active
\def'{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {^\bgroup\prim@s}%
  {\futurelet\next\h@ngrqtest}%
}
\@makeother\'
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[K''^{2} x\]

\noindent\begin{minipage}{10em}
\begin{hangpunct}
`abc def ghi abc def ghi abc def ghi abc def ghi' abc
\end{hangpunct}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that `'` works as expected in math mode and also that the closing quote is hanging in the `hangpunct` environment.